# Is there a way to get Intellisense to work in subdirectories?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been revisiting a bot that I've made with Discord.JS a while back, and something I've been struggling with for a while is that whenever working in subdirectories (e.g. `myproject/commands/moderation`), or any file outside of `index.js` for that matter, I don't get the Intellisense suggestions for discord.js but instead have to type everything manually.

Is there any way to get Intellisense to give me suggestions in subdirectories? Or, more likely, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either switch over to TypeScript and type annotate your values, or use JSDocs when defining your functions. If you're already using TypeScript, then you need to declare the shape of the data to use.

TypeScript:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import type { CommandInteraction } from "discord.js";

interface Command {
   data: SlashCommandBuilder,
   execute: (interaction:CommandInteraction) => void;
};

module.exports = {
   data: ...,
   execute(interaction) {

   }
} satisfies Command;
```

JSDocs:

```js
// Command file

import { CommandInteraction } from 'discord.js'; // If using ESM
const { CommandInteraction }  = require('discord.js'); // If using CommonJS

module.exports = {
   data: ...,
   /**
    * 
    * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
    */
   execute(interaction) {
      
   }
};
```

[image]

[JSDocs Guide](https://jsdoc.app/)
[TypeScript Guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)